# WSDL with imports in the binding section

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl

Where can I get some sample WSDLs that have import tags in the binding section? I need it to verify a code that I have written to flatten WSDL after resolving the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSRP WSDL has imports in the bindings and other sections as well:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrp/v2/wsrp-service.wsdl

Comment: the following import is broken:
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsrp:v1:bind" location="wsrp_v1_bindings.wsdl"/>

Comment: I hadn't realised that. For the purpose of testing the WSDL flattener you could just create your own copy of the top-level WSDL which removes the v1 related definitions.

Comment: Is it actually possible to flatten a WSDL document where the imports introduce definitions in foreign namespaces?